# passing data from hook to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

can i passing data from hook to view, If is it possible please explain.

for example

```
 $hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'Varify_user',
    'function' => 'user_project',
    'filename' => 'varify_project.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array('')
);
```

i want send some array data varify_project.php(hook file) to view.

Comment: you mean you want to add some array data to your view ? like `$this->load->view('view',$data);` but `$data` is your array in hooks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do so

**application/core/MY_Loader.php**

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    static $add_data = array();
    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
       self::$add_data = array_merge($vars, self::$add_data);
       return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array(self::$add_data), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```

**application/config/hooks.php**

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = function() {
    MY_Loader::$add_data['hello'] = "Hello World";
} ;
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer to add an explanation to why and how your code solves the problem.

Comment: I agree with @Mephy, and the same feedback has been offered on your most recent contribution. Since no edit has been made on this question, I am downvoting, with apologies. If you would be willing to add a sentence or two, I will gladly remove the DV.

Comment: I am realy don't understand, what could be added to these some strings of simple code. it, seems, is clear for those, who works with Codeigniter's hooks

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to add additional data at the time of loading the view, you could extend the core loader class like this:

**application/core/MY_Loader.php**

```
<?php
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $vars['hello'] = "Hello World";
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```

the `$vars['hello']` would then create a variable that you can use in any view called `$hello` and could be repeated to create any number of variables providing that you wanted them to be used on every page in your application.

Comment: Hi Ben thnx really.... good try by you... ... But splash58 proper explain the code.

Comment: @PavnishYadav I don't see any explanation at that answer, only just codes.If you think this answer is also OK why not up vote it too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment [splash58's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29718179/10053030) so I'm adding this here in case it is useful to someone.

Due to _ci_object_to_array() not being available anymore and sending an error the custom loader code should be (as it is in core since 3.1.3) :

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    static $add_data = array();

    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
       self::$add_data = array_merge($vars, self::$add_data);
       return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars(self::$add_data), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```