# CodeIgniter Hook: Get data from controller's method

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, hook

I've defined a hook in `config/hooks.php` something like below:

```
$hook['post_controller'][] = 
    array(
        'class'    => 'notify',
        'function' => 'sendEmail',
        'filename' => 'notify.php',
        'filepath' => 'controllers'
    );
```

Now this hook function will run after each controller's method executed. And it's running the way I want it to run. So upto this everything is fine.

Now let say I have a controller called `dashboard` and a method in it called `index`. In the index method I'm calling different model method and fetching data and storing it with different variables.

Now I want to use those variable in my hook `notify-sendEmail` method.

I'm not sure if this is even possible or not. If it is possible and anyone has done that kind of functionality please help me!

**Basically my question is :** Can we access all object data from current controller method in hook controller method.

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715760/passing-data-from-hook-to-view-in-codeigniter

Comment: With `params` we can pass an array to view? But how can I get `dashboard ->index` method's variables in hooks.php to assign it to `params`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use array to pass your data into your hook. for example: in your index method on dashboard class, userdata already store in `$userdata`:

```
// create property for userdata into big object
$this->userdata = $userdata;
```

then in your hook notify. you need to check the userdata property is exist or not?

```
function sendEmail(){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $required = array('email', 'subject', 'body'); // asume these parameter required

    // required userdata property. if property not set then print error
    if (!property_exists($CI, "userdata"))
    {
        echo "userdata required";
        return; // do nothing.
    }

    // if userdata is not array then print error
    if (!is_array($CI->userdata))
    {
        echo "invalid format userdata";
        return; // do nothing
    }

    // still here? it means userdata property exist and it's array
    $config_email = array();
    foreach($required as $key => $value)
    {
       if (!array_key_exist($value, $CI->userdata))
       {
            // some required parameter not exist.
            echo "field ".$value." is required";
            return;
       }

       // passing data into $config_email
       $config_email[$value] = $CI->userdata[$value];
    }

   //`do your stuff here to send email..
   // $config_email already set userdata. you still can modified them

}
```